# Is there an open subset of $~\mathbb R~$ that contains no rational numbers??

Tags: analysis

Is there an open subset of $~\mathbb R~$ that contains no rational numbers?

Comment: Yes, $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

Assume $(a,b)$ is a non-empty open interval.  There is some positive integer $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n}<b-a$.  Therefore, there is some integer $m$ such that $\frac{m}{n}\in(a,b)$.  Hence, evey non-empty open interval in $\mathbb R$ contains a rational number,

Answer (score 1):

Try $\varnothing$.

Excluding that, no. One could show that every open set in $\mathbb R$ is a (countable) union of open intervals, but there is no open interval containing only irrational numbers in the first place.

Comment: There is no need to show that $\mathbb{R}$ is second-countable - one can just pick any open ball (given by openness) which is precisely an open interval in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the empty set. Otherwise no because between every two numbers there are infinitely many rational numbers..

Answer (score 0):

As previous answerers have already noted, $\emptyset$ is the only such set. Moreover, a more general statement is true:

> Suppose $X$ is a topological space and $A$ is its dense subset. Then the intersection of $A$ with any non-empty open subset of $X$ is also non-empty.

The proof is by contradiction. Suppose, $B$ is a non-empty open subset of $X$, such that $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Then $\exists b \in B$ (because $B$ is non-empty) and that $b$ both does not lie in $A$ and is not a limit point of $A$ (by definition of limit points). However, contradicts our assumption, that $A$ is dense in $X$. Q.E.D.